# An inequality involving limit inferior and limit superior

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, inequality

I have the following assertion to be proved for $a_n > 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$
\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\mathrm{lim \inf}} \  \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\mathrm{lim \inf}}\ a_n^{1/n}
$$

I am totally stumped as $a_n$ can have arbitrary behavior. Any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Take $r>\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$. Prove that the inequality $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<r$ occurs infinitely often.